# Calculating a percentage from non-standard numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

`50, 25, 13`

and I would like to know how to calculate what `25` is as a percentage of the total amount (which is 88... 50 + 25 + 13...).

Thanks!

Comment: what is the dataset? string, json etc..?

Comment: `var percent = (25 / 88) * 100;`?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  Also, what do you mean by 'from odd numbers'?  50 isn't odd.

Comment: What do you mean by 'calculate what 25 is as a percentage of the total amount'?

Comment: @Rocket - That's true. It's a little emo sometimes, and its mom dresses it funny, but that's no reason to label it "odd".

Comment: @Joel: 25, on the other hand, that's odd.

Comment: Odd numbers - as in ones that do not add up to 100... nevermind though. Accepted answer. Question over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function CalculatePercent(value, total)
{
    return 100 * ( value / total );
}

var x = CalculatePercent(25, 88);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add them all together, divide by 100 and multiply by 25.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code for you:

```
percentage = element_value/sum(array) * 100
```

Where `element_value` would be 25 in your case.

Comment: It would be safer to put parentheses around *element_value/sum(array)*. Just in case.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, but I am curious: safer how?

Answer (score 0):

```
//input array is the data set to use for the calculation
//indexNum is the array location (index) to use to figure out the percentage for
function calculatePercentage(inputArray, indexNum) {
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0, len=inputArray.length; i<len; i++) {
    sum = sum + inputArray[i];
  }
  return (inputArray[indexNum] / sum) * 100;
}

//example usage
var dataSet = [50, 25, 13];
//find percentage that 25 is
$percentage = calculatePercentage(dataSet, 1);
```